Некорректная запись данных в json
есть небольшая проблема, я учусь писать на python, решил написать небольшую программу для себя, программа будет записывать все мои доходы и расходы и в дальнейшем выводить информацию по дате. При записи в json файл запись происходит следующим образом:
[
    [
        {
            "Income": {
                "receipt_date": "15.06.2024",
                "money_salary": 7500,
                "work_salary": "wew"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Expense": {
                "purchase_date": "15.06.2024",
                "money_spend": 5000,
                "place": "magazin"
            }
        }
    ]
]

прикладываю часть кода, где описывается сама запись:
def write_json(dict_operations):
    try:
        data = json.load(open(OPERATIONS_PATH))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = []

    data.append(dict_operations)

    with open(OPERATIONS_PATH, "w") as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

Прикладываю функцию записи доходов для примера:
def append_income():
    user_input_money_salary = int(input("Сколько денег ты заработал?\n"))
    user_input_work_salary = input("Введи место работы\n")
    income = Income(money_salary=user_input_money_salary, work_salary=user_input_work_salary, state="Income")
    return {
         income.state: {
             "receipt_date": income.receipt_date,
             "money_salary": income.money_salary,
             "work_salary": income.work_salary,
         },
    },

То, где я нашел похожий код запись происходит корректно, т е списком словарей, а не как у меня списком списком словарей, как я понимаю из-за этого я не могу вывести информацию из json файла
